How do I access fields in Supabase foreign-key table?
I've got a fairly simple database set up in Supabase. There are two tables: transactions and payees. The transactions table has columns for id, created_at, date, amount, and payee. The payees table has columns for id, created_at, and name. The transactions.payee field is set up as a relationship to the payees.id field.
I can query the sample data I've loaded and get a list of transactions for a given payee by doing this:
select * from transactions where payee = 2

However, this displays the payee id (i.e. "2") instead of the payee name, which is what I'd like to see. Some googling turned up a fairly complicated-looking "join" statement; I was able to duplicate it and get the desired result, but A) it seems overly complex given what I assume is a fairly common use-case for relational data, and 2) I have no idea how I would extrapolate it to include other foreign table data (i.e. what if I wanted to add a job and a bank account later).
What is the correct way to access fields in the foreign table?

This is SQL, you need to join transactions and payees in your from, and then you'll have access to the fields of both.
